# Как вернуть предыдущее значение после уменьшения строки через StringBuilder.setLength()?

Tags: java, строки

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Ivan");
        sb.setLength(3);
    }
}
```

Мы задали длину, а как потом вернуть предыдущее значение? То есть в данный момент он выдаст "Iva", а как потом работать с "Ivan".

Comment: Создать еще одну переменную , точно такую же как и sb перед sb.setLength(3);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Откатить» уменьшение длины для того же объекта интерфейс `StringBuilder` не позволяет, т.к. если увеличить длину снова ([`setLength(4)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int))) строка будет дополнена нулевыми символами.

### Нормальный подход

Поэтому, вместо отмены операции сохраняйте копию `StringBuilder`. Это можно сделать с помощью конструктора копирования:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Ivan");
StringBuilder backup = new StringBuilder(sb);
sb.setLength(3);
System.out.println(sb); //Iva
sb = backup;
System.out.println(sb); //Ivan
```

### Подход курильщика

По документации, `StringBuilder` не обязан сохранять символы за своими границами и, при уменьшении длины, теоретически мог бы очистить память (в данном случае, для символа `n`). Но очищать память каждый раз было бы накладно и `StringBuilder` сохраняет остаток строки если ее не затрут при последующем обновлении.

Соответственно, технически, восстановить строку можно, только для этого нужно обновить внутренние переменные `StringBuilder`. Сделать это через методы самого `StringBuilder` нельзя, т.к. переменные хорошо [инкапсулированы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Но это можно сделать через рефлексию. Это проблемный подход, т.к. во-первых теряется читабельность кода, во-вторых, мы не можем рассчитывать на документацию. Названия внутренних классов, переменных и поведение `StringBuilder` могут измениться из-за чего код будет мало того что непонятным, так еще и хрупким.

Теперь, когда я объяснил почему этого делать не надо, я могу объяснить как это сделать.

Шаг 1. Читаем [код `StringBuilder`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/72f33dbfcf3b/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuilder.java). Проверяем, что `setLength` при уменьшении длины не очищает внутренний массив. Обнаруживаем, что за длину отвечает поле `int count` класса-родителя [`AbstractStringBuilder`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/72f33dbfcf3b/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java). И класс, и поле объявлены с пакетным уровнем доступа.

Шаг 2. Пишем код:

```
//где-то наверху
import java.lang.reflect.*;

...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Ivan");
sb.setLength(3);
System.out.println(sb); //Iva

//РЕФЛЕКСИЯ: НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ В РЕАЛЬНОМ КОДЕ
//получаем поле
Field countField = StringBuilder.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("count");
//получаем доступ
countField.setAccessible(true);
//устанавливаем нужное значение
countField.set(sb, 4);
System.out.println(sb); //Ivan
```

Шаг 3. Запускаем, радуемся, и используем нормальный подход.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Особенно понравился подход курильщика)

Comment: @AntonSorokin Спасибо :)